# Checking nested conditions in a spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a nested condition which I am trying to convert

```
if (rewards_curr_tier != 1 && rewards_curr_tier != 2 && rewards_curr_tier != 3) {
    detailBps.append("2")
    detailBps.append(stagNumberFormat(9999.99))
  }
  else if (sparkUtil.getRowDataInteger(currentRow, "rewards_curr_tier") eq 3) {
    detailBps.append("0")
    if (curr_floor_limit > ytd_net_purch) detailBps.append(stagNumberFormat(curr_floor_limit - ytd_net_purch))
    else detailBps.append(stagNumberFormat(0.0))
  }
  else {
    detailBps.append(String.valueOf(sparkUtil.getRowDataInteger(currentRow, "rewards_next_tier")))
    if (currentRow.getAs("amt_rmngto_nxtier") == null) detailBps.append(stagNumberFormat(sparkUtil.getRowDataDouble(currentRow, "floor_limit")))
    else detailBps.append(stagNumberFormat(sparkUtil.getRowDataDouble(currentRow, "amt_rmngto_nxtier")))
  }
```

When i am using chained when it does not work as expected

```
when(col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(1)
        && col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(2)
        && col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(3), concat(lit("2"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(lit(9999.99)))).
        when(col("rewards_curr_tier") === 3 && col("curr_floor_limit") > col("ytd_net_purch"), concat(lit("0"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(col("curr_floor_limit") - col("ytd_net_purch")))).
        when(col("rewards_curr_tier") === 3 && (col("curr_floor_limit") < col("ytd_net_purch")), concat(lit("0"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(lit("0.0")))).
        when(!(col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(1) && col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(2) && col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(3)) && (col("amt_rmngto_nxtier") === null), concat(col("rewards_next_tier"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(col("floor_limit")))).
        when((col("rewards_curr_tier") === 1 || col("rewards_curr_tier") === 2 || col("rewards_curr_tier") === 3) && (col("amt_rmngto_nxtier").notEqual(null)), concat(col("rewards_next_tier"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(col("amt_rmngto_nxtier"))))
```

Is there a way i can use nested `when().otherwise(when())` in spark.

Here is what i tried so far but i was unsuccessful.

```
when(col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(1)
        && col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(2)
        && col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(3), concat(lit("2"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(lit(9999.99))))
        .otherwise(when((col("rewards_curr_tier") === 3
                         && (col("curr_floor_limit") > col("ytd_net_purch"))),writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(col("curr_floor_limit") - col("ytd_net_purch"))).otherwise(concat(lit("0"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(lit("0.0")))))
        .otherwise(when(!(col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(1) 
          && col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(2) 
          && col("rewards_curr_tier").notEqual(3))
          && (col("amt_rmngto_nxtier") === null), concat(col("rewards_next_tier"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(col("floor_limit"))))
          .otherwise(concat(col("rewards_next_tier"), writeHeaderAndTrailerUdf.stagNumberFormatUDF(col("amt_rmngto_nxtier")))))
```

Comment: I don't see otherwise in your code. Yes you can use when().otherwise(when())

Comment: @firsni Hi, I am not sure how the if else condition could be translated using the when otherwise. I tried but i was not successful

Comment: I have added to the question of what I tried so far. Any help is appreciated

Comment: it seems to be correct. How are you using the when condition. Inside withCOlumn ?

Comment: No I am using it outside withcolumn.

Comment: How are you testing it then ? How do you know that it doesn't work ?